# Este mensaje parece peligroso. Como evitarlo?

Tags: phpmailer

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Envio correos desde phpmailer utilizando una cuenta de gmail comun y corriente. La cuenta es equipoaular@gmail.com.
Tengo una pagina donde al registrarse los usuarios reciben un link de activacion de su cuenta para poder entrar. La pagina es aular.ml y tiene certificado ssl, sin embargo los correos a los usuarios llegan con el mensaje en rojo "este mensaje parece peligroso" y no permite clickear los links. El codigo que utilizo para enviar el mensaje es el siguiente.
Alguno paso por algo similar? Cuales suelen ser las razones para que esto suceda? lei que si mi correo no coincide con el link que mando sucede esto. Es decir tendria que tener un correo estilo equipoaular@aular.ml pero como no estoy seguro no quisiera gastar en un correo corporativo sin antes tenes ver si puedo hacerlo gratis ya que basicamente esta pagina es solo de aprendizaje.

**Para agregar informacion en la pagina mail-tester verifique el correo desde el cual envio los mensajes a los usuarios y tiene un puntaje de 8.5/10, lo malo en que se encuentra en 3 listas negras. 2 de Sorbs y una de una pagina llamada Backscatterer.org . Esto podria ser la causa? en fin tengo muchos dolores de cabeza y aun sigo averiguando como sacar mi correo de estas listas negras. Lo unico que busco es saber si alguno paso por esta experiencia y si pudo solucionar el problema. Muchas Gracias de antemano . Saludos**

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

try {

//Server settings
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;                                       // Enable 
verbose debug output
$mail->isSMTP();                                            // Set mailer to 
use SMTP
$mail->Host       = 'smtp.gmail.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP 
servers
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   // Enable SMTP 
authentication
$mail->Username   = 'equipoaular@gmail.com';                     // SMTP 
username
$mail->Password   = '';                               // SMTP 
password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                                  // Enable TLS 
encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port       = 587;                                    // TCP port to 
connect to

//Recipients
$mail->setFrom('equipoaular@gmail.com', 'EquipoAular');
$mail->addAddress($email);     // Add a recipient


// // Attachments
// $mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
// $mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name

// Content
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to 
HTML
$mail->Subject = 'Activacion Aular';
$mail->Body    = '

          <br>
          Por favor, haga clic en el siguiente link para activar su cuenta, 
  luego sera redireccionado a la pagina principal para que pueda acceder 
   normalmente:
          <br>
          <a 


  href="'.$base_url.'Home/Activation/'.$activation.'">'
 .$base_url.'Aular/Home/Acti 
  vation/'.$activation.'</a>

          </html>

';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

$mail->send();
return 'Registro realizado correctamente, por favor revise su correo para 
activar su cuenta. Si tiene algun problema para activar su cuenta por favor 
envíenos un correo a equipoaular@gmail.com';
} catch (Exception $e) {
return "Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
}








}
else
{
return 'Ya existe este mail registrado en el sistema';
}

}
else
{ 
return 'Mail invalido o no Existe';
}
```

Comment: solo haciendo un poco de follow up, pudiste resolver tu problema? Conozco una cuenta que esta sufriendo por lo mismo y capaz alguien mas necesita la info.

Answer (score 0):

El problema no viene tanto con la configuración en phpmailer. Si no por el contenido que estás incluyendo, el mensaje que muestras tiene toda la apariencia de un mensaje falso o de spam. Corrigiendo ello, tus mensajes podrían empezar a llegar a bandeja de entrada sin la advertencia, otra recomendación sería que empieces a usar un correo con dominio propio. Aquí encontré una guía que explica perfectamente lo que debes hacer:
https://doc.solymail.com/gmail-marca-correos-como-peligrosos/